# Renaming Power Pivot Column

Tags: excel, powerpivot

The program exporting my data set renamed all the columns.  I am trying to use "rename column" in Power Pivot to change the headings to the new headings.  It works fine on all nut the first one.  When I rename this one, it moves it to the last column on the imported data for no apparent reason.  This is only on the spreadsheet itself- the data model spreadsheet preview still looks the same.  Though I am trying to rename it from "Call #(Item)" to "Call No.", it does not seem to matter what I name it, it always moves, and only on that column.

Sorry I can't provide the file (too much confidential info), but has anyone seen this before, or have any ideas?  I'd rather not re-build the sheet!  This data is tied to a bunch of Pivot Tables; no vba for it to screw up on this one.

Comment: Can you share the power M code?

Comment: Why does the column order matter?